# Java Script alert box while text box in readonly

Tags: javascript

I have a Scenario to display alert box like "You cannot Enter the Values" when user clicking the text box while the text box is in Read Only.

**Java Script:-**

```
 function functionServerDisable()
    {    
    document.getElementById("txtServerName").readOnly=true;        
    }
```

**Aspx Code:-**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtServerName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

I don't know how to popup the alert box particularly user try to enter the data in that text box which is in Read Only mode.

Comment: If the `input` is just `readonly` and not `disabled`, you should be able to handle `events` like `click`, `keyup`, `keypress`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to the "focus" event, even if the input is `readonly`:

http://jsfiddle.net/y8vvj0q0/1/

```
test.addEventListener('focus', function(){
    alert("You cannot Enter the Values"); 
});
```

Comment: alerts coming multiple times

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use `onfocus` event in your input element?

```js
    function functionServerDisable()
    {    
     document.getElementById("txtServerName").readOnly=true;        
    } 
    functionServerDisable()
    
    function checkelement(el)
    {
     if(el.readOnly == true)
     {
      alert("Read only.");
     }
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtServerName"  onfocus='checkelement(this)'>
```

Comment: I am using Server control text box.. No onfocus event is in text box server control @Wracker

Comment: what do you mean by text box? Do you mean an ASP.NET element? Becauase your post is only tagged with Javascript tag so I'd suggest you to provide us with more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onkeydown function to show alert sample code look like this :-

```
<input type="text" readonly="true" onkeydown="validate()" />
<script>

function validate()
{
alert("You cannot Enter the Values");
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am using server controls and I set that text box read only in java script @praveen.

Comment: I am not getting what you actually want . can you explain your problem in details @dinesh.k

Comment: you have used onkeydown="validate()" in html text control... but i am using server control. in this there is no onkeydown event..                <asp:TextBox ID="txtServiceName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>